# good tool for indenting JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, converters

Can you suggest any tool to re indent minified JavaScript files and compressed CSS files?

Comment: Er, gzip doesn't change indentation. Are you thinking of *minification* instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hi I guess you mean beautify it ,

1. for javascript :
   http://jsbeautifier.org/

   for css :
   http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Answer (score 6):

I like this website for reformatting/prettifying CSS:

http://procssor.com/

Answer (score 3):

I use Chrome for daily development now...if you're in the same boat, the [PrettyPrint extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nipdlgebaanapcphbcidpmmmkcecpkhg) is excellent for this.

You get indentation *and* syntax highlighting to make it much easier to read.  Even better, just clicking the minified file link from view-source (or going directly...any way you navigate to it works) gets you there, no copy/paste steps involved.
[image: Pretty Print Preview]

Answer (score 3):

[Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) will do it for JS. Set "Optimization" to "Whitespace only" and check the "Pretty print" box. For CSS, the CSS tab of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (with no other add-ons) seems to work reasonably well, although saving the beautified code by copy-and-pasting is slightly difficult but possible (you have to use the keyboard, and then re-indent the copied lines in a text editor).

Answer (score 2):

Altough maybe overkill for this task, many IDEs can reformat minified JavaScript. E.g. [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) where you can use the menu element *Code -> Reformat Code...* The free version of IntelliJ will suffice. I guess Jetbrains simpler IDE for HTML/JavaScript development, [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/), can do this as well, as well as other IDEs like Eclipse and NetBeans

Answer (score 2):

If you use Firefox with Firebug you may install Yslow: it has some good tools like "All JS Beautified" and "All CSS Beautified". You will like it =)

Comment: Also, IE9 will have an option to format minified JavaScript. It's available in Platform Preview 6: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/28/html5-using-the-whole-pc-sixth-ie9-platform-preview-available-for-developers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See our [SD Formatter for ECMAScript](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/ECMAScriptFormatter.html).